# Blank page after deploying to github pages

Tags: github-pages

Here are the steps I did to deploy to github pages:

1. Install the gh-pages package as a "dev-dependency" of the app

   `npm install gh-pages --save-dev`
2. Add homepage property "homepage":

   "http://{username}.github.io/{repo-name}"
3. Deploy script

   "scripts": {
   //...
   "predeploy": "npm run build",
   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
   }

   `npm run deploy`
4. Setup source to the gh-pages branch.
   [image]

I go to the link and find a blank page with an empty console. I've looked around and everyone suggests these 4 steps, and nothing seems to work.
I use npx create-react-app to setup my React application.
Here is the link to my repository: https://github.com/yuivae/yuivae

Please let me know if you have any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

2 minutes I posted this thread I found the answer. I needed to change the react-router-dom path setting from
`<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />`

to

`<Route exact path="/{app-name}" component={Home} />`

because when deploying to gh pages by default I change `/` homepage path to the `http://{username}.github.io/{repo-name}`
After making this change I pushed, commited and deployed again and 10 seconds later it worked.